# PHP variables definition: comma separated vs visibility keyword repeated

Tags: php

I have many variables to define in a class (db credentials, api keys etc), which way is more efficient?

```
class Config{
    private $var1 = "xyz";
    private $var2 = "xyz";
    private $var3 = "xyz";
}
```

or:

```
class Config{
    private 
        $var1 = "xyz",
        $var2 = "xyz",
        $var3 = "xyz";
}
```

Comment: I guess it's personal preference. To me both look fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its User preference mostly, but I **definetly** prefer this way:

```
class Config{
    private $var1 = "xyz";
    private $var2 = "xyz";
    private $var3 = "xyz";
}
```

because you instantly see what visibility the variables have.
Aswell you might get a problem if your using annotations, for example:

```
class Config{
    /** 
    * \Some\Kind\Of\Model\Namespace
    */
    private $var1 = "xyz";
    /** 
    * \This\Is\A\Repository
    * @inject
    */
    private $var2 = "xyz";
    private $var3 = "xyz";
}
```

This could be quite hard if you use the second variant :). But in the end its user preference.